# SourceKitService crashed and Simulator failed

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm totally novice as programmer. I'm trying out the Swift and Parse. After I had added Parse.framework and Bolts.framework and all the dependencies I got SourceKitService crashed. I tried #include  instead #import  but it didn't work for me. iPhone Simulator failed as well. The problem is solved only if I delete the #import .

Help me please to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you did not include the framework itself. Add the framework to your project.

- In the project navigator, select your project
- Select your target
- Select the 'Build Phases' tab
- Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
- Click the '+' button
- Select your framework
- (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the 'Frameworks' group

Note: from How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?